# ng new failing with Angular CLI 7.2.1

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I recently upgraded Angular CLI to 7.2.1. After upgrade I realized that while creating a new project using

ng new hello-ng-world

The command fails with following error.

```
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ource-map":"0.1.x"},"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-15T04_01_29_782Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

I checked the log file and found following lines

```
2298 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for mini-css-extract-plugin@0.4.4 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...","webpack-cli":"^2.0'
....
2316 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for portfinder@1.0.17 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...82V3Kq5OEdhCZQ8nOUUQ/'

2352 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ource-map":"0.1.x"},"'
2352 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2352 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
```

Not able to proceed with the project creation. Please suggest what can be done.

**Edit 1:**
Ng version details (ng --version)

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.1
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.1
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.1
@schematics/angular          7.2.1
@schematics/update           0.12.1
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.2.2
```

Comment: can you add "ng --version" results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to force cache clean to make it work. I used the following command.

```
npm cache clean --force
```